# Using JDBC connection with property config Throwing outofmemoryerror

Tags: java, xml, spring, model-view-controller, ibatis

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/vod6?autoReconnect=true" />  
    <!--  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/vod2?autoReconnect=true" /> -->
    <property name="username" value="voddb" />
    <property name="password" value="vod@123" />

</bean>
```

above config xml working fine .

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
</bean>
```

When I am trying to configure jdbc.property and configure them throwing error  out of memory

Can you please explain what i am missing?

```
mysql.database=MYSQL
mysql.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/vod?autoReconnect=true

mysql.username=voddb
mysql.password=vod@123

mysql.initialSize=4
mysql.maxActive=30
```

property file

Comment: Exception in thread ""http-bio-8081"-exec-3"  this is print after executing 10 to 15 queries.

Comment: you need to add some connection pooling

Comment: can you please add property file also?

Comment: Post the logs.  Looks fine to me, Provided you have configured placeholders and other necessary stuff somewere

Comment: That's not the cause of the exception. Look elsewhere.

Comment: @DevendraSingh DBCP means DataBase Connection Pool.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes It is, but for achieving connection pooling properly, need to add some more properties.

Comment: Offtopic: It looks like you've just provided credentials to your DB hiding the first digits IP - what's the point? Only 1 thousand tries and someone is inside. (If it's not restricted by other means). Consider removing your username/password. No need to ask for troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm whether the placeholder is mentioned correctly in applicationContext.xml file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:catalina.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

If this is configured correctly please try removing mysql.initialSize=4 mysql.maxActive=30 from properties file and test, this may be thr root cause. Because this is the additional property you have mentioned in properties file

You can try configuring these maxActive,initialSize values in xml itself as property.

```
<property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="180"/>
   <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
   <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="900000"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="4"/>
```